Shellac/Waterproof edges of laminate particle board
What can I use to seal the edges of utility sink cabinet made from particle board?
I had a bad cartridge and water leaked and destroyed the edges—the laminate is separating. I am starting with a new cabinet and would like to protect it.

Thanks.

I'm confused. Are you asking about sealing the tiny joint between sheets of laminate, or do you intend to seal the panel under the laminate before you apply it? Please revise to be more clear.

I treat the cut, or sawn, edges of particle board when they are in areas that are likely to get occasionally wet. I use a "heavy" varnish.
However, that damage was to a "sealed" edge and I would not have varnished that.
If the cabinet will suffer more frequent wetting then use different materials instead of particle board. How about some plastic - that can be had in similar thicknesses. And it should be able to provide sufficient support to the door so should look "ok".

Agree, laminated particle board is a poor choice for a counter in a wet location.
